# Termux and Termux11 change root/home directory

Tags: linux, termux

as default termux use /data/data/.../home as home directory and we access file in home, but we can't use or see (permission) for other subdirectory, that which make sense application like intelij or netbeans or eclipse can create project but if want open or run application we goes to problems , that comes this app cant see subdirectory and think there is no file or folder. In this case how can I change  termux main directory from that into /sdcard ?

Comment: Note that `/sdcard` is mounted with noexec option by Android, which means you can store files there but it is not possible to execute anything that is saved there. This affects all apps and processes.